# tor tutorial "speaking to russia" stuck at 45 - 50%

Tags: python-2.7, tor

when I try to follow the tutorial (https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) about how to start up Tor I keep getting stuck at 45% and **sometimes** at 50%. I am using windows 8, python 3.4 and the LiClipse ide.

> [1mStarting Tor: [0m [34mApr 26 12:47:21.000 [notice] Bootstrapped
>   0%: Starting[0m [34mApr 26 12:47:21.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 45%:
>   Asking for relay descriptors[0m
>   [34mApr 26 13:04:00.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors[0m

The script looks like this, the change I have made myself here is to use `requests` library instead of `urllib` to rquest data from a source but I'm not getting to that part of the code here anyway. This is basicly a copy of the code at the tutorial page using SocksiPy.

TorConnector.py:

```
from io import StringIO
import socket
import requests

import socks  # SocksiPy module
import stem.process

from stem.util import term

SOCKS_PORT = 7000

# Set socks proxy and wrap the urllib module

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

def query(url):
  """
  Uses requests to fetch a site using SocksiPy for Tor over the SOCKS_PORT.
  """

  try:
    result = requests.get(url)
    return result
  except:
    return "Unable to reach %s" % url



# Start an instance of Tor configured to only exit through Russia. This prints
# Tor's bootstrap information as it starts. Note that this likely will not
# work if you have another Tor instance running.

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print(term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE))


print(term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)

print(term.format("\nChecking our endpoint:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))
print(term.format(query("https://www.atagar.com/echo.php"), term.Color.BLUE))

tor_process.kill()  # stops tor
```

I have also tried moving the TorConnector.py script file in to the `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages` folder and run it from a command prompt with `python TorConnector.py` but same thing happens, I am still stuck on 45%.

Also, if I end Tor.exe process when its stuck at 45% it tells me this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\gatsu\My
>   Documents\LiClipse Workspace\TorCommunicator\TorConnector.py", line
>   53, in 
>       init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\stem\process.py", line 246, in
>   launch_tor_with_config
>       return launch_tor(tor_cmd, args, torrc_path, completion_percent, init_msg_handler, timeout, take_ownership)   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\stem\process.py", line 136, in
>   launch_tor
>       raise OSError('Process terminated: %s' % last_problem) OSError: Process terminated: Failed to open GEOIP file
>   C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip6.  We've been configured to
>   use (or avoid) nodes in certain countries, and we need GEOIP
>   information to figure out which ones they are.

I hope it helps to figure out why this is making me get stuck.

I do not even have this file: C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip6

Comment: should the file `geoip6` be generated or added on install maybe?

Comment: same happens when using python 2.7.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the `geoip` and `geoip6` files in the tor browser folder (D:\Program\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor) and copied them to C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Roaming\tor which then made me reach 100%.

> [1mStarting Tor: [0m [34mMay 01 23:28:53.000 [notice] Bootstrapped
>   0%: Starting[0m [34mMay 01 23:28:53.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%:
>   Connecting to the Tor network[0m [34mMay 01 23:28:54.000 [notice]
>   Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop[0m [34mMay 01
>   23:28:54.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit[0m
>   [34mMay 01 23:28:55.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done[0m [1m
>   Checking our endpoint: [0m [34mUnable to reach
>   https://www.atagar.com/echo.php[0m

Answer (score 2):

Related to the [answer provided by @Alter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833010/4503129).
In a MacOs Sierra, a tor_process config that works (solving this issue) is

```
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd = '/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/Tor/tor.real',
    config = {
        'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
        'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
        'GeoIPFile': r'/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor/geoip',
        'GeoIPv6File' : r'/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor/geoip6'
    },
    init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can specify where the geoip and geoipv6 currently are by passing them into your config. See the [TOR manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#GeoIPFile) for a complete list of config options.

```
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
    'GeoIPFile': r'C:\Program Files (x86)\tor-win32-0.2.8.9\Data\Tor\geoip',
    'GeoIPv6File' : r'C:\Program Files (x86)\tor-win32-0.2.8.9\Data\Tor\geoip6'
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

as a side note, if you had this error. You need to kill the TOR process that was stuck at 45% before you run another (in windows, go into task manager and find/kill 'tor)'