# Python scraping TOR, script "To Russia, with love"

Tags: python, web-scraping, tor, beautifulsoup

I am trying scrape with BS4 via TOR, using the [To Russia With Love](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) tutorial from the Stem project.

I've rewritten the code a bit, using i.a. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957271/7326714), and it now looks like this,

```
SOCKS_PORT=7000

def query(url):

output = io.BytesIO()

query = pycurl.Curl()
query.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
query.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'localhost')
query.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, SOCKS_PORT)
query.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME)
query.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, output.write)

try:
    query.perform()
    return output.getvalue()
except pycurl.error as exc:
    return "Unable to reach %s (%s)" % (url, exc)

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
    if "Bootstrapped " in line:
       print(term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE))

print(term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
   tor_cmd = '/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/Tor/tor.real',
   config = {
      'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
      'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
      'GeoIPFile': r'/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor/geoip',
      'GeoIPv6File' : r'/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor/geoip6'
},
       init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)

print(term.format("\nChecking our endpoint:\n", term.Attr.BOLD))
print(term.format(query("https://www.atagar.com/echo.php"), term.Color.BLUE))
```

I am able to Establish a Tor circuit, but at "checking our endpoint", I receive a the following error,

```
Checking our endpoint:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-804-68f8df2c050b>", line 40, in <module>
print(term.format(query('https://www.atagar.com/echo.php'), term.Color.BLUE))

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stem/util/term.py", line 139, in format
if RESET in msg:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What should I change to see the endpoint?

I've temporarily solved it by changing the last line of the above code with,

```
test=requests.get('https://www.atagar.com/echo.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(test.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

but I'd like to know how to get the 'original' line working.

Comment: you might want to post your code, otherwise people can't help you! Looks like you're giving it a string when it wants a bytes-like object, you can convert e.g. by using `b` . [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010551/how-to-convert-between-bytes-and-strings-in-python-3) SO post might be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

Comment: @patrick. I added the code.

Comment: have you tried changing the `url` variable  in here: `query.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)` to a byte string? see here on 
[input handling](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/unicode.html#unicode): *Under Python 3, as PycURL invokes the write callback with bytes argument, the response must be written to a BytesIO object* ; also has a template to copy

Comment: I realise I do not fully understand the code. I've checked your advice and have set `url=b'https://www.atagar.com/echo.php'`. Besides that I've left the code unchanged but to the last line, where I now have `print(term.format(query(url), term.Color.BLUE))` in stead of my temporary solution. This results in the same error :(

Comment: Changing your return to `return output.getvalue().decode("utf-8")` should fix it.  Note that you may need to change utf-8 to another encoding but I'd try that first.

Comment: @drew010: Thanks! Worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Python 3, when that code was made for Python 2. In Python 2, `str` and `bytes` are the same thing, and in Python 3, `str` is Python 2's `unicode`. You have to add a `b` directly before the string to make it a byte string in Python 3, e.g.:

```
b"this is a byte string"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this doesn't seem to solve my problem. I think it might be something with the `query()` command in the last line of the code.